# Shortcut Keys for Moving Desktops in Mission Control in Mountain Lion 10.8.x?

Tags: keyboard, macos, desktop

Are there shortcut keys for moving a Desktop in the array of Desktops in Mission Control?

I can now do this manually using the mouse by dragging and dropping, but I would like to do this with shortcut keys. Sometimes they even get re-arranged on their own (not sure how that even happens).

Comment: They are probably getting reordered based on when you used them. You can turn this off in System Preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably I don't believe this is possible. As you've probably noticed, there are no user-accessible options for this in System Preferences' Keyboard Shortcuts. As far as I can determine, there aren't any scriptable interfaces either (plists, Applescript). Options for building your own program seem to be pretty limited as well, according to [a mailing list post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescriptobjc-dev/2011/Aug/msg00068.html) I found. The most you seem to be able to do programmatically is [get the current number of open spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768684/osx-lion-applescript-how-to-get-current-space-from-mission-control).

The only way to possibly do this without some serious OS X hacking is to use something like [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) to do some GUI scripting to do the dragging for you. However GUI scripting is always a bit messy, and you'd need to account for the changing positions of the desktops, depending on how many are open, etc. I suspect that's not exactly what you were looking for, but it's probably the closest you'll get, unless someone finds something I didn't. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do this by using cmd+arrow(left or right)key

Comment: The OP is asking for ways to rearrange desktops, not simply switch between them.